# Building A Generic Coupon Service System

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database-schema, coupon

I work in a food e-commerce company and I am re-desigining a coupon service.

A coupon can have a lot of rules like:

```
a)for what users it is valid
b)For what restaurants it is valid
c)For what area it is valid
d)min amount
etc etc
```

The current system handles all this rule with each rule being represented as a column is MySQL: http://pastebin.com/6KDC0iC8

However,since Rules for coupon will keep on changing we cannot afford to create column everytime.Or can we? Is there a way to make it generic without losing the power to query like:

```
a)what all coupons belong to this restaurant
b)what all coupons belong to this area
```

I am thinking to use mongo db for this.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

here's my suggestion to your scenario. Just my preliminary thoughts, so if you want me to elaborate just let me know.

It might indeed not be very scaleable if you have to create columns for each property. I suggest you store the properties of coupons which have a one-to-many or many-to-many relationship in separate tables.

I can imagine a situation like this:

```
Coupon
  id
  ...

Restaurant
  id
  ...

Area
  id
  ...

CouponsInArea
  coupon_id
  area_id

CouponRestaurantValidity
  coupon_id
  restaurant_id
```

These will probably not change a lot.

It's also possible that certain properties are valid for a coupon or not. You could solve this in a more generic way like this:

```
CouponProperty
  coupon_id
  property (a string)
```

Which you can then query by retrieving in a similar fashion to this:

```
select coupon properties where coupon_id is coupon.id
```